# Starting application by file open

Tags: android, android-intent

I created a music player and now I would like to implement a functionality that if I click a file (for example in Total Commander) it will open in my application. It already works on desktop but now I would like to also implement this feature in Android.

I know it must have been asked before but I couldn't find the answer.

I already found out that I need to define an intent-filter in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

I did it and now my application opens (or I can choose it) if I click a music file. But now I need to do something in the java part (I do believe in the main activity onCreate function) too. How do I handle this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please supply some source code, otherwise it will be difficult to support you.

Comment: I modified my question to include the part regarding intent-filter. But I have no idea what should be in the Java class.

Comment: I have posted an answer regarding how you can process the from your position. Let me know if this was useful to you

Comment: Thank you. This was really useful. I implemented it and works great. Unfortunately only as long as my activity is running. If I close the activity but let service running, it freezes at start. Have a look at this topic if you have any idea what might be wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425127/start-main-activity-from-notification-fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent filter you specified, is already a step into the right direction.
Now other (Explorer-like-) Applications can start your app.
As a next step, you need to receive the data in the activities `onCreate(...)` function. This can be done like that:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get the intent that started this activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri data = intent.getData();

    // Figure out what to do based on the intent type
    if (intent.getType().equals("audio")) {
        // Handle intents with audio ...
        String filePath = data.toString();
        // Do some handling here !
    }
}
```

First you need to capture the Intent, that other apps use, to call your app. The intent contains the path of your file (as URI) structure. The only thing you need to do then is to get the URI String and get the path of your music file out of it.

Information about the intent filtering can be read here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters